# Definition before construction on the stack? Similar to pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor, stack

I have a simple question regarding classes.

Consider the following object Apple (which has the default constructor removed).

```
class Apple
{
private:
    bool _fruit;
public:
    Apple(bool fruit) : _fruit(fruit) { }
};
```

Now declaring it on the stack/heap.

```
Apple p(true);
Apple * o = new Apple(true);
```

Okay, seemingly as the second one is a pointer, it means that I don't have to declare it directly.

I can just do **Apple * o;** and construct it later as **o = new Apple(true);**

But what about on the stack? Declaring **Apple p;** would give me a compilation error.

How can I construct p later without having to do so directly on the definition? Much appreciated.

Comment: You just can't do that.

Comment: For objects the declaration and definition are same i.e. is while declaring itself you're defining it and the comipler has to allocate the space for the object to creat it.

Comment: Alright then, that solved it I suppose. It's not possible.

Comment: It may help - why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Nemanja Boric: I've noticed some classes used in external libraries that forced me to declare stack objects and immediately initialize them from the constructor. My goal was to do so later, but I guess I just can't.

Comment: boost::optional can do this on the stack, but it incurs the overhead of a bool I believe: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You are free to separate allocation and initialization (construction), even when you want to allocate memory on the stack. Though you probably need a good reason to do so.

- You can allocate memory with no initialization by simply allocating an **array of bytes**.

  ```
  char space[sizeof(Apple)];
  ```
- The constructor can be called without allocation using the **placement new**.

  ```
  Apple& o = *new (space) Apple(true);
  ```
- In the end, do not forget to **call the destructor manually** before space goes out of scope.

  ```
  o.~Apple();
  ```

Comment: Joking aside, alignment issues are waiting to bite you.

Comment: That's true. I know that `new char[N]` is guaranteed to return a memory block properly aligned for all uses, but I know about nothing similar in case of allocation on the stack. That has to be resolved by hand, or maybe there are compiler extensions which could help.

Comment: In C++11 there's `alignas`, `alignof` and `std::aligned_storage`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, and you shouldn't try it, as the whole point about declaring objects on stack is **automatic** initialization and destruction.

If you are searching for a way to implement **lazy initialization**, you are searching in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As for lazy initialization - it's not what I want. I don't even know what it is - google time.